# Yucca problem: brown spots on stem and leaves

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, yucca

I am new here and here is my problem and thank you for your help! :)

I just noticed that my Yucca is having some problems: if you can see there are small brownish spots on the pleace where leaves come out of stem, that inner "pocket" is turning brown, also feels like leaves are not so firmyl attached to the stem anymore and can be easily torn off.

What am I dealing with here? Like some sort of fungus, mold? Please tell me there is a way to treat it, I don't want to get rid of my poor green baby. :(

THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP!

[image]